# Get divs within viewport inside a wrapper div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to get elements which is:

- Inside a div with overflow: scroll
- Is in viewport

Just like the following picture, where active div (5,6,7,8,9) is orange, and the others is green (1-4 and >10) :

[image]

I just want the mousewheel event to add "active" class to div 5,6,7,8,9 (currently in viewport). View my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrducnt/Luzqx/1/)

```
$('.wrapper').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
   //addClass 'active' here
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. I would have re-factored it, but only to show the concept.

Firstly I would attach this to `scroll` event and not `mousewheel`. There are those among us that likes to use keyboard for scrolling, and you also have the case of dragging the scrollbar. ;) You also have the case of touch devices.

Note that with this I have set `overflow:auto;` on wrapper, thus no bottom scroll-bar.

With bottom scrollbar you would either have to live with it becoming tagged as *in-view* a tad to early, or tumble into the world of doing a cross-browser calculating of IE's `clientHeight`. But the code should hopefully be OK as a starter.

### »»[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/DJgm3/)««

```
function isView(wrp, elm)
{
    var wrpH = $(wrp).height(),
        elmH = $(elm).height(),
        elmT = $(elm).offset().top;
    
    return elmT >= 0 && 
           elmT + elmH < wrpH;
}

$('.wrapper').bind('scroll', function (e) {
    $('div.box').each(function(i, e) {
        if (isView(".wrapper", this)) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you should likely refactor in such a way that `.wrapper` height is only retrieved once per invocation, or if it is static, at page load etc.

---

Update; a modified version of `isView()`. Taking position of container into account. This time looking at dolphins in the pool.

### »»[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/X9fdL/)««

```
function isView(pool, dolphin) {
    var poolT = pool.offset().top,
        poolH = pool.height(),
        dolpH = dolphin.height(),
        dolpT = dolphin.offset().top - poolT;
    return dolpT >= 0 && dolpT + dolpH <= poolH;
}
```

Comment: Just another question, how can I get the right offset().top value when div.wrapper position is absolute? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DJgm3/6/

Comment: @mrducnt: I also noticed you animated the margin. Played around a bit with it myself. It makes for some challenges especially when scrolling down (as elements get moved up when margin increases.) It can be fixed with  various tweaks. [This is one draft attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/X9fdL/10/). You could also look into `scrollIntoView(true)`, add extra pixels to the variables in `isView()` etc. Most is dependent on tweaking the margin start/stop to be correctly aligned with the height of the wrapper.